# Win7 registry not running vbs with multiple batch files

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, vbscript, registry

I have created a computer initialization script that allows for a) a batch file that syncs the PC with a time server, b) a batch file that activates Windows to a license server, c) displays a change log text file, d) allows the computer name to be changed via input from the user, and e) adds the users name to a text file on the desktop.  The script is to be run every time the computer boots therefore, a registry entry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run has been added.  When I simply run the script by itself everything functions as usually, but when I reboot the computer to have the script run on its own I only get the first batch file to run and not the other two.  However, the remaining portion of the script continues. I am not sure if this is a problem with the script or a problem directly related to the Win7 registry Any help would be appreciated...

See script below...

```
    '==============================================================================='
    '    Script Name       : Computer Initialization
    '    File Name         : ComputerInitial.vbs
    '    Creation Date     : 2012-11-27
    '    Update Date       : 2014-02-19
    '    OS                : Windows 7
    '
    '
    '==============================================================================='
    '**Start Encode**
    Option Explicit 'Enforce strict naming
    Dim WSH, FSO
    Dim objComputer, objWMIService, objOperatingSystem, objNetAdapter
    Dim strTitle, strVersion, strThisPC, strComputername, strCompNameRegPath
    Dim strWorkgroup, strCurrent_CleanStatus
    Dim strCCS, strTcpipParamsRegPath, strIPAddress, strSubnetMask
    Dim strGateway, strGatewayMetric, strCompCleanStatus
    Dim colMEM, colNetAdapters, colOperatingSystems
    Dim errEnable, errGateways
    Dim strTime, strWin, strLog


    'Setup scripting environment
    Set WSH = CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Set target PC for WMI
    strThisPC = "."

    'Set the Title for any dialogs
    strTitle = "Workstation Initialization"

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Section 1 - Update Time
    Dim strTimeUp
    Dim shell
    set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    strTimeUp = "cmd /c timeupdate.bat"
    shell.Run strTimeUp, 0, True
    WSH.Popup "Current Time and Date has been updated.",0, strTitle 'Inform user

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Section 2 - Activate Windows
    Dim strWinAct
    set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    strWinAct = "cmd /c windowsActivate.bat"
    shell.Run strWinAct, 0, True

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Section 3 - Display Change Log
    Dim strChLog
    set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    strChLog = "cmd /c changelog.bat"
    shell.Run strChLog, 0, True
```

Below is the code for timeupdate.bat

```
    net time \\192.168.101.101 /set /y
```

Below is the code for windowsActivate.bat

```
    slmgr /skms 192.168.101.13
    slmgr /ato
```

Below is the code for changelog.bat

```
    start "" "C:\Users\Cell User\Desktop\changelog.txt.lnk
```

Comment: Do you see your opup when the script runs at login? How do you know the rest of the script completes?

Comment: Add some logging to the VBScript (and perhaps the batch files as well) and also check the return value of the `Run` methods, so you see what's going on. As a side note: you only need a single `WScript.Shell` instance. There's no need to create multiple ones.

Comment: Bond - The first popup appears "Time and Date has been updated." which requires the user to click ok.  The second bat normally has two popup windows appear after windows validates the license.  These windows and the Change log text file are not popping up but the rest of the script includes three more pop up windows that require user input.  Those windows appear without a problem. Ansgar - I will add some reporting today and add that to my post. Thanks!

Comment: `cmd /c call name.bat`  <--- does that change the behaviour?  Does your batch file execute another script without a `call` keyword?

Comment: I have added the code of the batch files in my original post.  I have tried separating each batch call into separate vbs scripts and I experience the same issue.  I am beginning to think this is a Win7 registry problem and not a coding issue.  If I simply have the registry run each batch file at startup there is no issues, but I get command windows popup during there execution.  I wanted to put these in vbs so they run in the background at startup.  I appreciate all the help.